# any div with col-md-6 or col-md-12 invisible in safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 some things....
</div>
```

and its works fine in google chrome, but when I open the page in not displayed!

When I go to inspect the element nothing in the css has a `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` property.

When I remove the `col-md-6` or `col-md-12` class it works again.
Has anyone encountered this issue in safari, if so what was your solution?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/012y0xo3/2/

Thanks!

Comment: jsFiddle to demo what you're talking about?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay! Here is my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/012y0xo3/1/

Comment: You're using a different class, "col-md-6-fix"